# Having trouble emailing radio button values in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, codeigniter

I am attempting to email a form with radio button inside it, when I go to send the email. I get a returned value of just "on". I have set the name "value" correctly and tied it to form_validation code it all seems to "work" but the values are not being set correctly or emailed correctly. Code below.

Controller file:

public function contact_email()

```
{
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'is_numeric|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('comments', 'Comments', 'xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            $data["messages"] = "";
            $this->load->view('engage_header');
            $this->load->view('engage_nav');
            $this->load->view('contact/content_form', $data);
            $this->load->view('engage_footer');

        } else {

            $data["messages"] = "The Email has successfully been sent";

            $this->email->from(set_value("email"), set_value("name"));
            $this->email->to('test@test.com');

             $this->email->subject('Contact Request');

            $message  = "Name: " . $this->input->post('name') . "\n";
            $message .= "Email: " . $this->input->post('email') . "\n";
            $message .= "phone: " . $this->input->post('phone') . "\n\n";
            $message .= "Comments: " . $this->input->post('comments') . "\n";
            $message .= "Favorite Drink:" . $this->input->post('drinks') . "\n";

            $this->email->message($message);  

            $this->email->send();

            echo $this->email->print_debugger();

            $this->load->view('engage_header');
            $this->load->view('engage_nav');
            $this->load->view('contact/content_form', $data);
            $this->load->view('engage_footer');
        }   
    }
```

View File

```
<div class="form_wrapper">
        <div class="head_left">
        <p class="heading"><img src="/resources/css/images/mail_icon.png" width="32px" height="32px" class="mail_icon">Contact Us</p>
        </div>
        <div class="borders"></div>

        <div class="form_container_left">

        <?php echo form_open('/index.php/site/contact_email')?>
        <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label for="messages">How Can We Help?:</label>
        <textarea rows="" cols="" id="messages" name="comments"></textarea>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="reset_bar">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit_bar" value="Submit"> 


        </div>
        <div class="form_container_right">
            <p  class="optional_heading">Your Favorite Drink (optional):</p>
            <div class="soda_container">
            <img src="/resources/css/images/Soda.png" width="64px" height="64px">
            <center><p id="soda_text">Soda</p></center>
            <br/>
            <center><input type="radio" name="drinks" id="soda" value="soda"></center>
            </div>
            <div class="coffee_container">
            <img src="/resources/css/images/coffee.png" width="64px" height="64px">
            <center><p id="coffee_text">Coffee</p></center>
            <br/>
            <center><input type="radio" name="drinks" id="coffee" value="coffee"></center>
            </div>
            <div class="water_container">
            <img src="/resources/css/images/water.png" width="64px" height="64px">
            <center><p id="water_text">Water</p></center>
            <br/>
            <center><input type="radio" name="drinks" id="water" value="water"></center>
            </div>
            <div class="beer_container">
            <img src="/resources/css/images/beer.png" width="64px" height="64px">
            <center><p id="beer_text">Beer</p></center>
            <br/>
            <center><input type="radio" name="drinks" id="beer" value="beer"></center>
            </div>
            <div class="wine_container">
            <img src="/resources/css/images/wine.png" width="64px" height="64px">
            <center><p id="wine_text">Wine</p></center>
            <br/>
            <center><input type="radio" name="drinks" id="wine" value="wine"></center>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <?php echo form_close()?>
```

Comment: btw, never heard back from you about your last question - did the codeigniter form validation issue get solved? :)

Comment: FYI, preceding and proceeding slashes are not necessary in the `form_open()` function. Nor is `index.php`. You should just do `form_open('site/contact_email')`. To debug, try `die(print_r($this->input->post(),TRUE));` in your `contact_email` method.

Comment: @Raidenace yes the form validation issue was resolved! It was my stupidity that lead me with just a typo that messed everything up! Once changed all things worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to email radio button values they first must be set by declaring `set_radio` nested in the value parameter. Like so

```
<input type="radio" name="drinks" id="water" value="water" <?=set_radio('drinks','water') ?>>
```

There are numerous ways to recall this information back to your "controller" I just used a simple `$this->input->post('$variable')` worked.

This is how I called it into a message and is what worked for me.

```
    $message  = "Name: " . $this->input->post('name') . "\n";
    $message .= "Email: " . $this->input->post('email') . "\n";
    $message .= "Phone: " . $this->input->post('phone') . "\n\n";
    $message .= "Favorite Drink: " . $this->input->post('drinks') . "\n";
    $message .= "Comments: " . $this->input->post('comments') . "\n";
```

The name "value" set in your view must correlate with the value passed in the controllers `$this->input->post('')` parameter.

Thanks for everyone's help on this!!
Dyllen